# Are there quicker ways to find the eigenvalues of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

I need to find the eigenvalues of this matrix:
$$ A=
\begin{pmatrix}
1&4&16\\
4&16&1\\
16&1&4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Of course, I could do this by solving $\text{det}(\lambda I - A)=0$, but is there a shorter way to do this for this particular matrix which doesn't rely on making a lot of calculations by hand?

Edit: Not asking for homework help. I want to know if there is a 'smart' way to do this that exploits the structure of this matrix. This question was asked in a previous question paper of an online standardized exam which allows no calculator (except the basic on-screen calculator) and leaves approximately 3 min/question. So, having a smart way to do it is pretty much necessary.

Comment: One method you're trying: asking here and hoping others do the job for you. Another way would be doing the calculations not by hand, but with software on a computer.

Comment: @Professor Vector No, I genuinely wanted to know whether there was a 'smart' way to do this that exploited the structure of this matrix. I should have clarified: the reason I was asking was because this question was asked in a previous question paper of an online standardized exam which allows no calculator (except the basic on-screen calculator) and leaves approximately 3 min/question. So, having a smart way to do it is pretty much necessary.

Comment: You should add such pertinent information to your question, indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using @Arthur 's recognition that one eigenvalue is $\lambda_1 = 21$.

You know the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace of the matrix $= 21$.

Thus the remaining 2 eigenvalues satisfy $\lambda_2+\lambda_3=0$.

Also $\lambda_1 \,\lambda_2 \, \lambda_3 = \det(A)$ combining with the above, leading to, say,  $-21\lambda_2^2=\det(A)$, from which you can obviously find $\lambda_2$ and hence $\lambda_3$

Comment: I should've thought of trace and determinant rather than characteristic polynomial and long division. This is a lot faster.

Comment: @Arthur your insight with the row sums was key

Comment: It's all tricks I've seen before. I still think I ought to have spotted the trace and determinant. Oh well. Hindsight and all that.

Answer (score 8):

All rows sum to $21$, so $(1, 1, 1)^T$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $21$. To find the remaining two eigenvalues, you can divide the characteristic polynomial by $(\lambda - 21)$, and get a quadratic equation. The matrix is symmetric, so you know the equation has real solutions (real symmetric matrices always have only real eigenvalues, and orthogonal eigenvectors).

Comment: Is there any justification for this method ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas Justify what, exactly? That $21$ is an eigenvalue? I think I justified that. Dividing the characteristic polynomial by $\lambda - 21$? We know $21$ is a root of the characteristic polynomial, so it must be divisible by $\lambda - 21$. That we get a quadratic equation? The original characteristic equation is a cubic, and dividing by a linear factor makes it quadratic. That the remaining two eigenvalues are the roots of the new quadratic? Dividing a polynomial by a factor doesn't change where the other roots are.

Comment: No, I mean why that trick works ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas I do four or five tricks. I think I explained them all in my previous comment. Which one do you mean?

Comment: I mean how did you know that if all rows sum to the same number, $(1, 1, 1)$ is the corresponding eigenvector of that number.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Because that's how matrix-vector products work. You can think about it element-wise if you want, but I prefer to think in columns. A product $Mv$ is a linear combination of the columns of $M$ with the coefficients being the entries of $v$. Thus if all entries of $v$ are $1$, then $Mv$ is just the sum of the columns of $M$, which means that the entries in $Mv$ are the row sums of $M$.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Arthur- thank you so much! @onurcanbektas we have $Me_1 = e_1 + 4e_2 + 16e_3$, $Me_2 = 4e_1 + 16e_2 + e_3$ and $Me_3 = 16e_1 + e_2 + 4e_3$. So, $M(e_1 +e_2 + e_3) = 21(e_1+e_2+e_3)$.